# Make a simple-answer question form in J.S

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do you make a simple-answer question form in js?
I tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
    <script>
      function cipher1(){
        var val ="theanswer";
        if(val == (document.getElementById("cipher1").value)){
          alert("correct");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="bod">
    <div id="cipher1"style="display:none;">
      <input id="cipher1"type="text" value="write the answer here"/>
      <input type="button" class="but"value="answercheck"onclick="cipher1()"/>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But it doesn`t work.
please help!!!

Comment: you have a duplicate id on page (you can have only one id on page) `cipher1`

Comment: @Vasyl Zhuryk Thanks!

Comment: `getElementById("cipher1")` will select the first one in the page (which is a div) and a div has no `.value` so it will always be `undefined`. That's why `id` must be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Id must be unique. In your code you are associating 'cipher1' with div and input field. You can change to Id of the text field to cipher2. See the code below:

```js
  function cipher1(){
        var val ="theanswer";
        if(val == (document.getElementById("cipher2").value)){
          alert("correct");
        }
      }
```

```html
 <div id="cipher1">
      <input id="cipher2"type="text" value="write the answer here"/>
      <input type="button" class="but"value="answercheck"onclick="cipher1()"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try first to change the two duplicates ID

```
div id="**cipher1**"style="display:none;">
      <input id="**cipher1**"type="text" value="write the answer here"/>
```

Than remove display style from the parent div

Comment: I'm not sure `id="**cipher1**"` is a valid ID, and you didn't correct anything, it's still the same ID twice. If this is supposed to be a hint, you should rather show some correct code in your answer, for instance `id="cipher1"` and `id="cipher2"`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a duplicate id on page (you can have only one id on page) `cipher1`